# elasticsearch v7: search indices and count matches

Tags: elasticsearch

The query

```
PUT my_index-*
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

will find all documents with *foo*="bar" in indices whose name starts with "my_index-".

But how to get just the count of matches for each index, i.e. I would like to know only how many documents with *foo*="bar" exist in each index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
POST my_index-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```